# How do I copy from Vrapper on Eclipse in OS X to system clipboard

Tags: eclipse, vim

I use Vrapper in Eclipse on Mac OS X. I'm trying to get the vim-ish register contents that I obtained by yanking text with `y` on to the system clipboard. In regular Vim invoked from the command line, I have shortcuts mapped to make system calls to `pbcopy` that do the job. But Vrapper doesn't seem to read my `.vimrc`. Even if it does, those shortcuts don't work.

What's the best way to get the Vrapper clipboard contents onto the system clipboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like with Vim, you must specify the `"+` or `"*` register when you yank:

```
"+y
"*y
```

Just like with Vim, you can set Vrapper to use your system clipboard when yanking or deleting by adding this line in `~/.vrapperrc`:

```
set clipboard=unnamed
```

Also, if you use Vim for programming it is recommended to use a proper build instead of the default, if only to get clipboard support. Just install MacVim and forget about `pbcopy`.

Comment: It is ~/.vrapperrc  [ two "r" ]  instead of ~/.vrapperc, tried .vrapperc just does not work.